# Bound values are not getting updated from editable datatable without setting ID in JDK1.5

Tags: java, jsf, java-6, java-5, jsf-1.2

Bound values are not getting updated from editable data table without setting ID in JDK 1.5. But the same does work without setting ID in JDK 1.6.
Does anyone know why? Thanks

Code, Bean part

```
    public void setDataTable(HtmlDataTable dataTable) {
    this.dataTable = dataTable;
}

public HtmlDataTable getDataTable() {
    if (dataTable == null)
        setEditableDataTable();
    return dataTable;
}

private void setEditableDataTable() {

    dataTable = new HtmlDataTable();
    dataTable.setValueBinding("value",
            createValuebinding("#{testBean.stringList}"));
    dataTable.setVar("items");
    for (int i = 0; i < getDatastable().get(i).size(); i++) {

        UIColumn column = new UIColumn();
        dataTable.getChildren().add(column);

        HtmlOutputText header = new HtmlOutputText();
        header.setValue("Header "+i);
        column.setHeader(header);

        HtmlInputText input = new HtmlInputText();
        input.setValueBinding("value", createValuebinding("#{items[" + i
                + "]}"));
        column.getChildren().add(input);

    }

}

private ValueBinding createValuebinding(String valueExpression) {
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()
            .createValueBinding(valueExpression);
}
```

JSP part

```
   <h:dataTable binding="#{testBean.dataTable}" >
                </h:dataTable>
```

#### Solution

```
   Give id for the datatable
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimum code snippet which we can copy'n'paste'n'run ourselves to see the problem?